# Custom Product Configurator Using Javascript/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, prototypejs, shopping-cart

I know this is a pretty broad questions but for learning purposes I'm trying to create a site similar to https://knockaround.com/shop/sunglasses/custom/custom-premium. I'm having trouble finding tutorials on how to accomplish this. I'm sure I can create the dropdowns to switch the images for the product, but where would I start when trying to pass the merged image to the cart? Also, I'm pretty sure the website uses Magento and Prototype JS. If someone could get me started in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: the website you mentioned using shopify not magento

Answer (score 1):

Like this framework (http://fancyproductdesigner.com/), it must be merging the images on the server and created a single image saved with the cart entry.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't pass the "merged image" to the cart, but rather the configuration. If you look at the hash on the page, it changes depending on the settings: #custom/3/6/13/259
So what you're passing the cart is "3/6/13/259"

Comment: You're right about the configuration, but if you ad that item to the cart and then view the cart, the image in the cart is 3-6-13-259.png. It's not a configuration of 3 pngs like it is on the configurator page. My main question is how that image was generated and passed to the cart.